# Are questions about specific tasks and areas of research which use AI techniques on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

From what I've seen so far, most of the questions on the site currently seem to be either about AI in general or about common techniques and algorithms.

What about more specialized topics? Can people ask questions about e.g. the basic principles of computer vision or speech recognition? Both of these are areas of research which use AI techniques to a great degree.

Answer (score 3):

Certainly, assuming the questions are reasonably scoped. "What are the principles of computer vision?" would be way too broad and closed as such. More specific questions like "Can a computer know the difference between someone's face and a printed-out held-up photograph of that face?" would be interesting.

Do be careful that we don't get bogged down in the implementation, which is the subject of existing sites like Data Science. Programming is also off-topic, in my understanding. We're focused on the academic/somewhat-theoretical aspects of artificial intelligence.